# What are some good unofficial scenarios for Robinson Crusoe?

Tags: expansions, robinson-crusoe

Enjoying this great game and have finished all the scenarios. I know that there are several official mini-expansions and The Voyage of Beagle. I already own The Voyage and have no interest in buying minis.

What I really want to have is some PDFs with printable scenarios. If you have played and enjoyed some, please tell me about them.

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games Stack Exchange! Unfortunately, recommendation questions [are off-topic for this site](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1308/3389) because they are polls, and can't have a "correct" answer. Check out the [site tour](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already to see how this site is different from others.